# Create file from terminal

Tags: python-3.x

I don't understand logic of this task:
Create an app create_file.py that takes directory path, file name, file content from the terminal and creates file. There should be flags -d or -f:

If only -d flag passed, means all items after this flag are parts of the path.
python create_file.py -d dir1 dir2 - creates directory dir1/dir2 inside current directory.

If only -f flag passed, means first item is the file name.
python create_file.py -f file.txt

After pressing Enter it creates file file.txt and then terminal should ask you to input content lines until you input "stop":

Enter content line: Line1 content
Enter content line: Line2 content
Enter content line: Line3 content
Enter content line: stop
This creates file file.txt inside current directory with content:

2022-02-01 14:41:10
1 Line1 content
2 Line2 content
3 Line3 content
App should add current timestamp at the top and number lines. If file.txt already exists it should add content below:

python create_file.py -f file.txt

Enter content line: Another line1 content
Enter content line: Another line2 content
Enter content line: Another line3 content
Enter content line: stop
2022-02-01 14:41:10
1 Line1 content
2 Line2 content
3 Line3 content

2022-02-01 14:46:01
1 Another line1 content
2 Another line2 content
3 Another line3 content
If both -d and -f flags passed, app creates directory and file with content inside this directory.
python create_file.py -d dir1 dir2 -f file.txt

Enter content line: Line1 content
Enter content line: Line2 content
Enter content line: Line3 content
Enter content line: stop
Creates directory dir1/dir2 inside current directory and creates file file.txt inside that directory with content:

dir1/dir2/file.txt:

2022-02-01 14:46:01
1 Line1 content
2 Line2 content
3 Line3 content

It would be relevant to use:

sys.argv to read arguments from the terminal
os.makedirs to create directories

Questions:

1. But what should be in the sys.argv list?  argv = ['-f', '-d', '-f-d'] no?
2. What should be the logic of work, we read the entire argv list at once, then we enter the data into the console, or we read one element of the list, entered the data into the console, read the second - entered the data? There must be some other way to do it, but I don't understand how?

Comment: Stack overflow has a preview pane while you're typing out your question. It shows exactly how your question will appear. Please double check your formatting because as written your code in your question is almost unreadable.

Comment: Also take a look at [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), it takes care of all the command line argument parsing.

Comment: I know about argparse, but I don't understand what should be the logic of work? No code is needed for this.